# JQuery Mobile + Knockout , CSS Styles fails

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I'm using html5, JQuery Mobile and KnockoutJS, I Have a foreach template that renders a grid like GUI from an observable array.

However, when I add items to the bound array, the styles are not applied to any new items.
They appear unstyled, most of the times. 
some times they appear with style, but once the styling fails, it stays broken for as long as I run my app.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Snippet:

```
<div id="timeEntryList" data-bind="foreach: timeEntries">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
        <h1>some header</h1>
```

The odd thing is that it works *sometimes*.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess without any code. But I guess you 're saying jqm doesn't render properly after dynamically adding elements. That's right it doesn't. I guess it's like the list. And you probably can do something like `$('#mylist').listview('refresh');` but I don't know what sort of component you're talking about.

you can find [more info in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)

Answer (score 0):

jQM might not support more than one `data-role="header"` section. I would try conforming to their [standard page layout](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) with one header, one content and one footer section and see if that helps.

I've found that if I update my KO observables in `pagebeforeshow` I don't have to use `.listview('refresh')`